# Installing XP Office 2002 on Windows 7 in virtual XP mode

Tags: windows-7, installation, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2002

I'm running Windows 7 64bit and have successfully installed the virtual machine and XP mode. I'm currently running Microsoft Office Outlook 2007. I want to install Windows XP Office 2002 to get access to the Outlook software.

What do I need to do before I start the installation process?

I don't want the outlook 2002 software install to "stomp" all over the current installation of office within the windows 7.

Comment: How on earth did you get Microsoft Office 2002?! I just googled "Microsoft Office 2002"(skeptical that such a thing existed) it said 144,000 results(some from microsoft). I googled "Microsoft office 2003" I got 8.6 million results.  Office 97 gets 834,000 results, that's 5.7* more results than 2002, and the internet wasn't that popular in '97 compared to 2002. By the way with XP people used 2003  2007 and 2010.  2003 was fantastic. 2007 requires sp2, and 2010 requires sp3 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office

Comment: And no it won't stomp over anything. It's in a virtual machine. Even a Virus in a virtual machine won't stomp over anything outside it.

Comment: Office XP *IS* Office 2002.  
Microsoft Office 2000
Microsoft Office XP (2002)
Microsoft Office 2003
Microsoft Office 2007
etc.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the ISO in the XP VM or connect to it via a share and install it in XP.  If you installed Office / Outlook 2007 in Windows 7, then installing 2002 / XP in XP Mode won't touch the Windows 7/2007 install (XP Mode is a separate computer within your Windows 7 computer.